# NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED in Firefox with Selenium Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, firefox

I'm using Selenium 2.53.1 and JUnit 4.12 to build some tests for my application. My Firefox in 45.7.0 version.

But, I'm stuck at this point. When the application needs to call an `alert()` or `confirm()` in the js files, I get this error:

`NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED:`

I tried to look in others sites but I couldn't find nothing about. Anyone knows what it might be? Thanks in advance

DETAIL1: Doesn't matter if I click manually or use WebElement click() function

DETAIL2: When I open up a Firefox instance manually, that is, click in the Firefox shortcut on Windows, the `confirm()` call works normally. This only happen when Selenium starts Firefox.